# Issues checking the length of a viewmodel

Tags: nativescript

I've got a page with a list view:

```
<ListView items="{{ tasteList }}" visibility="{{tasteList.length&gt; 0 ? 'visible' : 'collapse'}}">
```

I'm trying to check the length of tasteList and toggling the visibility so the list view is only rendered if there are items in it, and I'm rendering a different layout in that case:

```
    <StackLayout visibility="{{tasteList.length = 0 ? 'visible' : 'collapse'}}">
```

In my test case, there are 3 items returned. With the above code, on initial page load the list is not visible and my StackLayout appears. if I navigate away from the page and come back, the listview IS displayed (as long as I don't empty the viewmodel0.

If I remove the condition and just make the listview visible all the time, the page loads the listview and the three items as expected.

It seems that the condition is checked before the view model is actual loaded and not updated subsequently. When I put `<Label  text="{{ tasteList.length }}" />` at the top of the page
 I see "0" for about 1 second and then it switches to "3" but the visibility isn't toggled on my ListView/StackLayout. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are suppose to use `==` or `===` on the expression (conditional statement for visibility) and more importantly you should mention the attribute before the expression, the one that should trigger change upon update.

**Example**

```
<StackLayout visibility="{{ tasteList.length, tasteList.length === 0 ? 'visible' : 'collapse'}}">
```

From docs, [Using expressions for bindings](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#using-expressions-for-bindings)

Comment: Thanks, mentioning attribute prior to the expression was the key